# How to use memcpy() function with dynamic allocated-struct

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct

```
typedef struct process {
    int pid;
    int burst_t;
    int io_t;
    int pri;
    int arrive;
    int wait;
    int turnaround;
    int work;
    int remain;
} process;
```

and fuction

```
void move_process(process* dest, int  *size_dest, process* src, int *size_src)
{
    memcpy(dest + (sizeof(process))*(*size_dest), src, sizeof(process));
    (*size_dest)++;
    (*size_src)--;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(process));
    memmove(src, src + sizeof(process), sizeof(process)*(*size_src));   
}

ready = (process*)malloc(sizeof(process)*numberOfProcess);
remain = (process*)malloc(sizeof(process)*numberOfProcess);
move_process(ready, &s_ready, remain, &s_remain);
```

In function move_process()'s last line,

I want to remove first process in process* src
but it does not work.

What should I do??

Comment: The `memcpy` and `memmove` arguments are suspicious

Comment: `memcpy(dest + *size_dest, src, sizeof(process));` ... and similar for the memmove()

Comment: maybe you are unaware that `src + 1` means to point to the next `process` object  (not to increment by 1 byte)

Comment: Your function signature makes little sense. Why do you need both size_src and size_dst? Why are they pointers? If the callee should allocate memory for dst, why are you using a parameter (incorrectly) and not the function return value?

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code:

- You should use `const` on the source pointer to make it clear that it's read-only.
- You should not cast the return value of `malloc()`.
- It's better to use `sizeof *dest` to "lock" it to the actual pointer, not repeat the type name.
- Sizes and array indices are better expressed as `size_t`, not `int`. Remember to print using `%zu` in that case.
- Remember that structures can be assigned, no need to use `memcpy` for structure values. The copy can be written: `dest[*size_dest] = src[*size_src];`, no function call needed.
- Remember that pointer arithmetic is *not* done in bytes.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `dest + (sizeof(process))*(*size_dest)` with `dest + *size_dest` to go `size_dest` locations forward. Similarly for memmove.

This should do the trick.

```
void move_process(process* dest, int  *size_dest, process* src, int *size_src)
{
  memcpy(dest + *size_dest), src, sizeof(process))
  (*size_dest)++;
  (*size_src)--;
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(process));
  memmove(src, src + 1, sizeof(process)*(*size_src));
}
```